celery.node error : -Failed to connect to the database: Error: Unsupported type: postgresql
const celery = require('celery-node');
const ingestData = require("../workers/dataIngestionWorker");
// Celery broker configuration
const broker = process.env.CELERY_BROKER_URL || 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//';
// Celery backend configuration (for storing results)
const backend = process.env.DATABASE_URL || 'postgresql://username:password@localhost:5432/credit_approval_system';
// console.log(broker, backend);
// Create a Celery instance
const cel = celery.createClient( backend, broker);
const dataIngestionTask = cel.createTask('data_ingestion', ingestData);
module.exports = dataIngestionTask;
I read that we can give postgres connection string in backend of celery but it is throwing error of unsupported type.
I expected it to work fine and create another table in my postgres db to store celery results, but it is throwing error.
